# Combine two touch monitors into one big touchscreen

Tags: windows, usb, display, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have two identical touch monitors installed side by side and want to use them as a single big touch screen.

Currently I'm using Windows 10, but switching to another OS is also possible.
The displays both get their video signals over HDMI and send the touch signals over USB.

Using both touch screens is not a problem as long as they are individual screens in Windows. However, I need them to act as a single screen because I need to run full-screen apps on them.

Using the Nvidia driver, I can combine the "display" part of the touch screens, so that they act as one large screen. This however messes up the touch input.

Is there a way to have both displays act as a single large screen while still having functioning touch input? I don't expect that this is possible without additional hard- or software, but you never know.
For multi-monitor setups without touch, there is an established product category called "multi-monitor controller" or "vieo wall controller" - is there something similar for touch displays?

What I already thought about was "intercepting" the touch signals from the displays, for example with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, then somehow combining the inputs there (which will have its own challenges, I know), and then let the board act as a mouse or other USB-HID to my PC.

But since this would obviously be a lot of work, I wonder if there are any better ways to do this.

Comment: Recommendations for hardware or software need to be made on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) sites

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. I'm not looking for HW/SW recommendations per se, more a general "this is doable in SW" or "you need HW for this"

Comment: Does this help? https://support.ctouch.eu/hc/en-us/articles/115003949829-How-can-I-setup-multiple-touch-screens-in-Windows-10-

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The "normal" setup of the two monitors as separate touch sceens is not the problem. What I'm trying to achieve is the two monitors acting as one single big touch screen.

Comment: For Future readers: I did not get this to work. At the end, it was less work to rewrite the App to not require one big screen but instead work on the two touch screens configured as separate screens. It's a shame though, since the "one big touchscreen" configuration would have made programming for it a lot easier.